# Python sorting a dictionary whose value is a multidimensional list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have the following dictionary:

```
DICT = {'ABC': [[u'2012-07-19', 1.22, 1, 1.22, 1, 0], [u'2012-04-26', 1.33, 210, 1.33, 210, 0], [u'2011-11-14', 1.25, 171, 1.32, 241, 70]], 
'XYZ': [[u'2012-02-17', 1.82, 59, 1.25, 182, 123], [u'2011-04-06', 1.50, 30, 1.18, 54, 24], [u'2011-01-06', 1.21, 38, 1.17, 41, 3], [u'2010-06-21', 1.28, 26, 1.28, 26, 0]]}
```

Values are two dimensional list.

How can I sort keys based on the third column of values.

Let me explain:
The third column minimum value of key 'ABC'  is 1.22 (among 1.22,1.33 and 1.32).
The third column minimum value of key 'XYZ'  is 1.17 (among 1.25,1.18,1.17 and 1.28).
Since 1.17 > 1.22 'XYZ' will be first and then 'ABC'.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the dictionary? If so, that is impossible on the account of being represented most likely as a binary tree, thereby not being sortable.

Comment: Your code example appears as though it will be very difficult for others to read or maintain.  I highly recommend creating a class, in this case.

Comment: @Nino: What do you mean?

Comment: @kojiro Thanks for your answer. I was trying with itemgetter in the itertools module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python builtin `sorted` with a key function to pick out the specific characteristic of the iterable you want to use as a sort key:

```
>>> [l[1] for l in DICT['XYZ']]
[1.82, 1.5, 1.21, 1.28]
>>> min(l[1] for l in DICT['ABC'])
1.22
>>> sorted(DICT, key=lambda k: min(l[1] for l in DICT[k]))
['XYZ', 'ABC']
```